# Limit the number of times an iPhone app is used

Tags: iphone, app-store, nsuserdefaults

Is there a way to limit the number of times an application is used in an iPhone (to implement the lite version)? I know I could use the UserDefaults, but if the user deletes and re-install the app, the limit would disappear.

I tought of using a webserver, but it is too much work for a simple problem.

Anybody had the same issue (and solved it)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there is a way. Because you have to store the data by some way, but then when the app is deleted, all of your data will be gone, it doesn't have registry like windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple will reject the app from the store if it limits the usage of the application.

Even if the app is a "lite" version, it should still be a fully usable application - maybe it'll be missing a few features, but Apple don't like it when you put time limits or number of usages limits on apps.

Comment: Thanks. It is kind of contradictory nevertheless... for instance I can limit the number of levels in a game... but I cannot let the player only use the game 50 times... well ok!

Comment: the reason being is they want the app to be usable the whole time it is on the phone

Comment: They're defending the user and making the developers do a workaround. It is legitimate, but sometimes a pain in the a**.